# Images added as backgrounds not showing in render

Tags: interface

I had to redownload Blender after my laptop was rebuilt. Now, when I add images as backgrounds they don't appear in a render like they did before and they have different property options. Attached- the smaller selection of options now

[image]

Comment: Empties won't render, even if they carry an image. Use image as plane instead.

Comment: @lemon yes! thank you. I just looked and there's no option to add an image as a plane. there was in my previous version but not this time

Comment: image as plane is a standard addon: just activate it

Comment: @lemon thank you so much for your help!